How to compare specific pairs of dates from multiple date columns and extract indices?
I have a data frame with columns of dates. The columns date_ind represent the column index for the date_cols. I want to compare pairs of date columns for each row specified by date_ind. Specifically, I want to find the earlier date between the pair and get the corresponding date_ind value for the earlier date.
For example,

1st row: date_ind1 = 1 and date_ind3 = 4, so I compare date_col1 and date_col4, and decide that date_col4 is the earlier date and earlier_date_ind should = 4
2nd row: date_ind1 = 1 and date_ind2 = 2, so I compare date_col1 and date_col2, and decide that date_col2 is the earlier date and earlier_date_ind should = 2

... and so on.
For ties, I want to choose an index that's smaller. e.g. row 4 has equal dates, and the earlier date index should be 1.
So far, I've tried getting the earlier dates based on this rule but wasn't sure how to go about extracting the corresponding date_ind values. Any help would be appreciated.
Data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  date_ind1 = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1),
  date_ind2 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, 4),
  date_ind3 = c(4, NA, 1, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA),
  date_col1 = sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-1-31"), by="day"), 8),
  date_col2 = sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-1-31"), by="day"), 8),
  date_col3 = sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-1-31"), by="day"), 8),
  date_col4 = sample(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-1-31"), by="day"), 8)
)

> df
  date_ind1 date_ind2 date_ind3  date_col1  date_col2  date_col3  date_col4
1         1        NA         4 2000-01-31 2000-01-11 2000-01-27 2000-01-10
2         1         2        NA 2000-01-15 2000-01-05 2000-01-25 2000-01-09
3         3        NA         1 2000-01-19 2000-01-20 2000-01-28 2000-01-19
4         1        NA         2 2000-01-14 2000-01-14 2000-01-30 2000-01-04
5         1         2        NA 2000-01-03 2000-01-22 2000-01-09 2000-01-14
6         3        NA         1 2000-01-10 2000-01-25 2000-01-03 2000-01-17
7         2         3        NA 2000-01-18 2000-01-30 2000-01-08 2000-01-11
8         1         4        NA 2000-01-22 2000-01-19 2000-01-07 2000-01-07

tried:
library(dplyr)
col_names1 <- paste0("date_col", df$date_ind1)
col_names2 <- paste0("date_col", coalesce(df$date_ind2, df$date_ind3))
df$earlier_date <- 
  sapply(1:nrow(df), 
         function(i) min(df[ i, col_names1[i] ], df[ i, col_names2[i] ]) ) |> 
  as.Date()

want:
  date_ind1 date_ind2 date_ind3  date_col1  date_col2  date_col3
1         1        NA         4 2000-01-31 2000-01-11 2000-01-27
2         1         2        NA 2000-01-15 2000-01-05 2000-01-25
3         3        NA         1 2000-01-19 2000-01-20 2000-01-28
4         1        NA         2 2000-01-14 2000-01-14 2000-01-30
5         1         2        NA 2000-01-03 2000-01-22 2000-01-09
6         3        NA         1 2000-01-10 2000-01-25 2000-01-03
7         2         3        NA 2000-01-18 2000-01-30 2000-01-08
8         1         4        NA 2000-01-22 2000-01-19 2000-01-07
   date_col4 earlier_date earlier_date_ind
1 2000-01-10   2000-01-10                4
2 2000-01-09   2000-01-05                2
3 2000-01-19   2000-01-19                1
4 2000-01-04   2000-01-14                1
5 2000-01-14   2000-01-03                1
6 2000-01-17   2000-01-03                3
7 2000-01-11   2000-01-08                3
8 2000-01-07   2000-01-07                4


A tidyverse solution:
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column('id') %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("date_ind"), names_to = NULL) %>%
  mutate(earlier_date = as.data.frame(pick(contains("date_col")))[cbind(row_number(), value)],
         earlier_date_ind = value,
         .keep = "unused") %>%
  slice_min(earlier_date, with_ties = FALSE, by = id)

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  id    earlier_date earlier_date_ind
  <chr> <chr>                   <dbl>
1 1     2000-01-10                  4
2 2     2000-01-05                  2
3 3     2000-01-19                  1
4 4     2000-01-14                  1
5 5     2000-01-03                  1
6 6     2000-01-03                  3
7 7     2000-01-08                  3
8 8     2000-01-07                  4


Thank you for a great solution! I was wondering if it would be possible to keep the columns date_ind1 ... date_ind3? I tried changing mutate(..., .keep = "unused") to "all" but the date_ind columns still seem to be missing

@nightstand Just bind the result back to df, i.e. ... %>% bind_cols(df)

Apparently col3 complements col2. We could combine them and use as index to subset the ind cols, remove prefix to get numbers.
> mapply(
+   \(x, y) as.integer(sub('date_col', '', names(which.min(df[x, y])))),
+   seq_len(nrow(df)),
+   t(within(df[1:3], {
+     date_ind2[is.na(date_ind2)] <- date_ind3[is.na(date_ind2)]; rm(date_ind3)
+   }) + 3) |> as.data.frame())
[1] 4 2 1 1 1 3 3 4

